# How to map object Id from DTO to existing object in database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper

I'm trying to map object Id to an existing object using automapper and EF core.
My dto accepts `LocationId` only, but I'd like to map full `Location` object in `WorkRecord` entity if object with such id exists in database, otherwise controller will return `BadRequest`.

DTO:

```
    public class WorkRecordCreateDto
    {
        [Required]
        public int? LocationId { get; set; }
    }
```

Model

```
    public class WorkRecord
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Location Location { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Post(WorkRecordCreateDto workRecordDto)
        {
            var workRecord = _mapper.Map<WorkRecord>(workRecordDto);
            _repository.GetRepository<WorkRecord>().Add(workRecord);
            _repository.SaveChanges();
            return Ok();

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have an EnityConverter for this:

```
public class EntityConverter<TDestination> : IValueConverter<int, TDestination>
{
    private readonly ISession session;

    public EntityConverter(ISession session)
    {
        this.session = session;
    }

    public TDestination Convert(int sourceMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return session.Get<TDestination>(sourceMember);
    }
}
```

To use this, you have to configure the mapper, that it can use DependencyInjection. We use Grace and it will be different in your environment:

```
container.Configure(c => c.ExportFuncWithContext<IMapper>((scope, staticContext, context)
                    => new Mapper(automapperConfig, t => scope.Locate(t))).Lifestyle.SingletonPerScope());
```

Now you can add the EntityConverter in the AutoMapper mapping:

```
CreateMap<WorkRecord, WorkRecordCreateDto>()
            .ReverseMap()
            .ForMember(d => d.Location, opts => opts.ConvertUsing<EntityConverter<WorkRecord>, int>(src => src.LocationId));
```